# C++: How to deal with the RAM consumed by unused empty vectors?

Tags: c++, algorithm, design-patterns

I have a C++ software that performs agent based simulations. In a simulation, there are `Population`s that contain `Patch`es that contain `Individual`s that contain two `Haplotype`s. Each `Haplotype` contain 12 vectors each serving to track different types of genes.

```
class Haplotype
{
    std::vector<A> genesA;
    std::vector<B> genesB;
    std::vector<C> genesC;
    std::vector<D> genesD;
    ....

};
```

In practice, however, a user will never use more than one or two types of genes. This means that each of these unused vectors consume a few bytes (two pointers at least). For simulations with lots of genes and few `Individual`s that is negligible. However, for simulations with few genes and lots of individuals these extra bytes might start to matter. Performance (both CPU time and RAM) is of prime importance.

Is there a nice design pattern that would allow me to deal with this issue? Something that could add the vectors into `Haplotype` on demand only?

Comment: Would `std::vector<std::variant<A, B, C, D>>` suit your needs? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant

Comment: As long as each type is similarly sized a variant could be a win. If not the overhead of empty vectors is generally around two pointers and a size_t.

Comment: `std::variant` will incur some constant overhead for *every* element in the vector.

Comment: I think this question is a bit under-specified. How many Haplotypes will you have? What are the sizes of A, B, C, ... etc.? What do you expect to do with them?

`std::vector<int>` is 24 bytes on my system. If you really have so many Haplotypes that 288 bytes of overhead for each one is unacceptable, then you are probably going to want something hand-optimized that takes data access patterns into account...

Comment: There is not really enough information to give a specific answer here. Can you elaborate more on the types `A`, `B`, `C`, `...` etc? Are they the same size? Similar sizes? etc? How many elements will the vectors contain? Etc...

Comment: @BrennanVincent and Galik. There is not much general rule to be made as the size of these vectors will vary drastically upon the user's request. A single vector has a size that varies between a few bytes (when usunsed), a few tens of bytes or 0.5 GB. When several vectors are being used, there is no reason to expect them to have a similar size. The number of types of gene used will vary upon request but typically I don't expect anyone to use more than 2 or max 3 types. The number of haplotypes can vary between a few hundreds to a few millions.

Comment: @Galik  I think `std::vector<std::variant<A, B, C, D>>` is really beautiful. With the `std::visitor` it offers a way to avoid the casting that you need if you would use `std::vector<Gene>`.
But now you have to filter the vector for the correct gene type to get to all A, B... vectors.
Maybe `std::vector<std::variant<A*, B*, C*,...>>` would help with the space? Everything is pointer-sized.
Downside - memory management...

Comment: @Remi.b What are the types A, B, C, etc.?

Comment: `bool`, several `unsigned int`, several `double`, several `unsigned short`, several are a class made of `unsigned short` and `std::vector<unsigned short>` and another one is a class is made of three `unsigned int`

Comment: How much to they vary in size?

Comment: @Galik A single vector can have a size that varies between a few bytes (when usunsed), a few tens of bytes or 0.5 GB. Some vectors have a constant size during the simulations, while others have size that vary (often starting at 0 at the beginning of the simulation and growing up to eventually maybe 0.5GB each).

Comment: I don't mean the vectors. I mean A, B, C, D etc... what is the smallest and the biggest (in bytes)?

Comment: Say, A, is 1 bit per object (`std::vector<bool>`). B is 3*4 bytes (3 `unsigned int`). C is one `unsigned int` plus one `std::vector<unsigned short>` (hence anywhere between about 8b to 0.1Mb per C object). Am I answering your question?

Comment: @Remi.b "In practice, however, a user will never use more than one or two types of genes" is this a hard guarantee or just "in practice"? Also, is it really worth it? I.e. is there a measured memory impact of the extra empty vectors or is this a premature optimization?

Comment: I am running simulations where only two vectors of constant size (18 bytes for one, 16 bytes of the other) are used. If I count 8 bytes per empty vector, there is 8 * 10 = 80 bytes used for these empty vectors. It results in ~70% of the RAM used for these empty vectors. To be fair, these simulations are just pilot runs and I am fine with their RAM usage. I was mainly curious as to whether it could be improved (without increasing CPU time) as I can imagine that it could become an issue for some eventual use in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I think no matter what you do, you will have to have some space reserved for the data to come.

A vector has the potential to "waste" some space that's not used. Also - the object itself uses some memory, like you said.

However, when you use arrays, you have full control.
with `std::vector<Gene>[] genes;` you can use exactly the memory you need.
But now you have to know which index is representing which type (A, B, C...). That information will cost you memory again...
Also you have to copy and reallocate the array in case you want to add another.

You could avoid to use the allocated memory for each vector by using pointers and initialize them with `nullptr`. Then you allocate them on demand.
That way you will only waste the space of the pointers.
The way you currently implemented it you will initialize each vector object(, and potentially some reserved space).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is what you are looking for but I think, instead of storing 12 vectors where only one or two are useful, you can store a vector of vectors which contains only the useful ones (using polymorphism).

For example you create a base class for you gene types:

```
class Gene
{
    // Make it pure virtual (abstract) for example
};
```

Then you create your 12 different types of genes inheriting this base class:

```
class A : public Gene // Gene type number 1
{
    // ...
};

...

class L : public Gene // Gene type number 12
{

};
```

So that, all your 12 types of genes are `Gene`.

Then, in `Haplotype`, you can store the useful genes as follows:

```
class Haplotype
{
    std::vector<std::vector<Gene*>> genes;
};
```

That way, you store only the genes that are useful in the vector and nothing else. Of course, this design using polymorphism implies that you store pointers instead of values.

You can add a method in `Haplotype` that retrieves the real type of its components (the dynamic_cast which succeeds) to make it imperceptible from the "user's side".

I don't know if this solution will be good for you, but I hope it can help.

---

**EDIT:**

If you are before C++17 and so cannot use `std::variant`, I think this could be an alternative.

Comment: This requires constant overhead for every gene. (Since you need to allocate it on the heap, *and* store a pointer to it in one of the vectors). How is this better than variant?

Comment: I never pretended it to be better than variant. It is just a design proposal. If it does not suits the needs of the OP, he will let me know. Don't be that aggressive, I'm just trying to help.

Comment: @BrennanVincent variant is at least the sizeof maximum element (+ some for tag). Os if there are "Genes" with size diff more that size of ptr, it'll take less mem. However, the real question should be "How is this better than OP's current implementation". Neither this, not std::variant seem worth it.

Answer (score 0):

If all the gene types are of roughly the same size, it might be a win to do something like this:

```cpp
union Gene
{
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
    D d;
};
class Haplotype
{
    std::vector<Gene> genes;
    int aEnd, bEnd, cEnd;
  public:
    A getA(int idx) {
        return genes[idx].a;
    }
    B getB(int idx) {
        return genes[idx + aEnd].b;
    }
    C getC(int idx) {
        return genes[idx + bEnd].c;
    }
    D getD(int idx) {
        return genes[idx + cEnd].d;
    }
};
```

Adding a new gene of a given type to the vector can be done in constant time (you don't need to push everything back), as long as you don't care about the order of individual types.

For example, if you need to add a B, you would move it to the spot of the first C, then move that to the spot of the first D, then push that on the end. You would then increment each of `bEnd` and `cEnd`.

For example:

Initially: `[A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, C1, C2, C3, C4, D1, D2, D3, D4, D5]`

Add the new B at bEnd: `[A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C2, C3, C4, D1, D2, D3, D4, D5]`

Replace the evicted C: `[A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C2, C3, C4, C1, D2, D3, D4, D5]`

Add the evicted D at the end: `[A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C2, C3, C4, C1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D1]`.

To remove a gene in constant time, you would do a similar thing in reverse. The point is to maintain the invariant that all As come before all Bs, which come before all Cs, which come before all Ds.

This scheme allows you to get away with less overhead: only one int per type (to store the end index), in exchange for much uglier code, a bit of extra time overhead when adding or removing genes, and the inability to keep each set of genes in insertion order. It is up to you whether those drawbacks are worth it.

Also, this design will incur overhead per element if the types have dramatically different sizes, since a union must be at least as big as its largest member.